# ブラウザを閉じて開くたびに証明書を毎回要求される

Tags: android

Android
ブラウザを閉じて開きなおすたびにクライアント証明書の選択を要求されます。
この証明書の選択を省略したいです。

IEのインターネットオプションにおける「既存のクライアント証明書が一つしか存在しない場合の証明書の選択」のような機能はないのでしょうか。
画面の遷移では要求されないので、セッションかなと思っていますが、よくわかりません。
何か方法ありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

＜状況＞
・証明書は一つのみインストールしています。
・アンドロイドVer8以上

Comment: もしかしたら、この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Request with automatic or user selection of appropriate client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44929645/9014308), [Client Certificate Android Https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891174/9014308), [How Chrome browser know which client certificate to prompt for a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40847638/9014308)

Comment: kunifさんありがとうございます！
見てみます